# Rails ajax to replace content not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a input text which on keyup sends the ajax request and gives response to replace the content. My form looks like this;

```
 = form_for(:search, :url => "/users/search", :remote => true) do |f|
   = f.label :user, "Type to find users"
   = f.text_field :user
```

The UsersController search action searches for the user based on the ajax data and it renders the search.js.erb template. My search action looks like this;

```
 def search
    @users = User.search(params[:user])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js{}
    end
  end
```

Now, the search.js.erb template is simple which is as;

```
$('.users_info').html(<%=j render @users %>);
```

The response is correct if I look in the firebug but does not replace the content in the page. If I place alert, it alerts the user. Why am I not being able to replace the existing content in the page. Is there something that I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it realy necessary to use js.erb? It looks like in your case you may simply

```
$('form').bind('ajax:success', function(e, data){
    $('.users_info').html(data);
});
```

If you really need, try:

```
$('.users_info').html('<%=j render 'search_user' %>');
```

Comment: I know now my mistake, I forgot to put quotes around the irb cpdes